# iOS Build upload failure from jenkins to hockey app

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, ipa, hockeyapp

I am getting below error when I tried to upload build (ipa) from jenkins to hockeyapp

"Got unexpected response code from HockeyApp: 200"

I have added team ID, upload version, ipa file, No release notes and allow Downloads as part of jenkins configuration hockeyapp.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I figured it out.

If we select upload app then there shouldn't be any issues.

But if we select upload version then appID from hockeyapp should be provided.